# Proof that contraction $ \rfloor$ is an anti-derivation

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

In geometric algebra, contraction by a vector $$ is an anti-derivation, meaning for all (possibly inhomogeneous) multivectors $A, B$, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\lc}{\rfloor}
 \lc (AB) = ( \lc A)B + A^\star(\lc B)
\label{1}\tag{1}
,$$
where $^\star$ denotes involution ($^\star = -$ and $(AB)^\star = A^\star B^\star$) and the left contraction $\lc$ is defined by
$$
A \lc B = \sum_{p,q} ⟨⟨A⟩_p ⟨B⟩_q⟩_{q-p}
$$
where $⟨\phantom{A}⟩_k$ is the grade $k$ projection.

I am struggling to prove eq. \eqref{1}.

---

I have however proven that $ \lc$ is an anti-derivation with respect to the wedge product;
$$
 \lc (A∧B) = ( \lc A)∧B + A^\star∧(\lc B)
\label{2}\tag{2}
.$$

Can anyone show how \eqref{2} implies \eqref{1}, or otherwise prove eq. \eqref{1}?

Comment: I don't know anything in this area but your title uses the left floor symbol and your post instead uses the right floor symbol. Intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of the identity
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\lc}{\rfloor}
 \lc A = \frac12(A - A^\star )
$$
makes for a very simple proof:

\begin{align}
 \lc (AB)
   &= \frac12(AB - (AB)^\star )
\\ &= \frac12(AB - A^\star B + A^\star B - A^\star B^\star )
\\ &= ( \lc A)B + A^\star ( \lc B)
\end{align}